# Создать файл на сервере Ubuntu с правами 777(rwx) для всех пользователей. Flask

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask

Есть приложение на Flaske, лежит на сервере Ubuntu. Задача приложения создавать/записывать/перезаписывать txt файлы, лежащие на сервере. Так как для пользователя, который заходит в это приложение по ссылке, даются права как o(other), то и файлы создаваемые им, создаются с правами только на чтение. Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Владельцем файлов, создаваемых Flask-приложением, будет пользователь, от имени которого запускается Flask-приложение, и он будет иметь все положенные права на чтение-запись. Откуда у вас взялся какой-то other — непонятно

Comment: Извиняюсь, неправильно понял логику работы.